# When two things should be done after something occurred

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

What is the adverb to say another thing is done, when the first thing is also done? is it "At the same time"?

Examples:

The task begins to process. ...... an email is automatically sent to the user.

My original sentence in which I used "meanwhile" is

> In the algorithm, after visiting a node which matches the beginning anchor “Results”, the state of the context changes into “Open” and the following nodes will be regarded in this context, **meanwhile**, a node labeled “Products” is created and added to the XML structure.

Comment: *When the task begins to process,* or *As soon as the task begins to process, an email is sent.* .

Comment: Algorithms are typically explained step-wise. I would reserve *meanwhile* for use with asynchronous processes only.  Do you mean "regarded as belonging to" when you write "regarded in"?  Not sure what you're referring to in that sentence by "the following nodes".

Comment: @TRomano maybe *following nodes will be treated according to this context*, they are counted as elements underneath of this context (scope). By Meanwhile simply I mean ALSO  but like to have a better word.

Comment: "Meanwhile" refers to something happening *concurrently*; it does not mean "also".  But what are the "following nodes"?  If you are referring to "Products", that statement is premature.  You could say "...a node labeled 'Products' is added to the XML structure within the scope of the current context."

Answer (score 2):

"At the same time" does work.

> At the same time the task begins to process, an email is automatically
>   sent to the user.

If you're looking for an adverb, you could use [simultaneously](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-thesaurus/simultaneously#simultaneously_1).

> When the task begins to process, an email is simultaneously
>   sent to the user.

With simultaneously "automatically" sounds redundant (as "simultaneously" implies the sending of the email is automatically done).

Comment: Thank you, I myself used "meanwhile" for a similar sentence, however I have heard meanwhile introduce something different but it also can be used to say something else is happening: *cook the sauce until it thickens, meanwhile start boiling the water for the pasta*

Comment: Compared to "meanwhile," (at least to me) "simultaneously" sounds much more "instant" in that there is virtually no delay between the two actions happening. With "meanwhile" I get the sense that there's a small delay between the actions. With your example on cooking, I interpret it as "start cooking the sauce and then start boiling the water" with there being a slight delay between the start of the cooking of the sauce and the start of the boiling of the water, though eventually both actions are occurring at the same time.

Comment: let me send my original sentence in the question, There I don't want to emphasizes the simultaneously  or not. just to add another sentence.

Answer (score 1):

In computing and communications, we often use the words concurrency (noun) and concurrently (adverb)

> After visiting a node which matches ..., the state of the context changes to "Open"; concurrently, a node labelled...

[Concurrently](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/concurrently)

> operating or occurring at the same time
>
> running parallel

Answer (score 0):

An appropriate idiom would be :

> kill two birds with one stone

Refer : [idioms](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/kill+two+birds+with+one+stone)